# Publishing data to 10000 clients at once continuously

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, redis, apache-kafka

I am building a project where the server generates data every second which must reach a variable number of clients (in order of thousands).No process happens on the server side. It receives a data from a third party WebSocket and forwards it to clients.

There are three ways I can think of.

1. Clients polling every second.
2. Using WebSockets
3. Using some sort of distributed queue.

I want to implement this using springboot2. 
The main concerns are

1. All the clients should receive the data of a particular second
   before the data for the next second is generated. Meaning the data should be published to all of them in less than a second.
2. Clients may be drop off in the middle. If the reconnect again they
   will get a snapshot of diff data at once and incremental data starts
   flowing from the next second.

I have some doubts regarding this.I am not able to simulate more than 200 concurrent clients due to hardware restrictions, so I am not able to come to a conclusion.

- Is there a distributed queue to which clients can subscribe and
  receive data? Something like Kafka but it should be able to handle
  100000 clients, who come and go dynamically?
- The data generated is very small and can be stored in memory. Should
  I store it in memory (Some map or redis cache) and clients keep polling with the last id they received so that I can send the data from memory? Will it scale?
- If we use WebSockets, can the server handle 10000 clients at once? If
  its possible how can solve the missing data problem?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: "can the server handle 10000 clients at once" Sure why not, throw more ram at it until it works?

Comment: "Should I store it in memory . ", if u have enough ram perhaps, but definitely use caching. so you can fetch it from the db once, and use the cache for everyone else

Comment: @Andrew 1.I get data from WebSocket, so cannot prefetch data. 2.Rather than one large machine, I want to run it on multiple smaller ones so I can control cost with the load.

Comment: [JeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) and [Pub-Sub](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter5#toc1).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you please provide some rough estimates (ram) and machines to solve this?

Comment: If you go with clients connecting to your service and keeping persistent connection over which they receive updates, please consider the case when your service goes down and all clients start reconnecting. Always use exponential backoff with random jitter for client retries, otherwise you'll essentially DDOS yourself. And it will make service recovery much harder.

Comment: @Pardha.Saradhi No. That is way too broad a question, and depends on entirely too many variables in ***your*** application. There is no one-size-fits-all scaling strategy.

Answer (score 1):

That use case is what JMS servers are used for, so instead of implementing everything yourself you might have a look at these servers, e.g. Apache AMQP.

Another solution you can try is using MultiCast where the distribution of the data is done by the network layer itself but that as well might bring you back to a JMS server that use this technique already hiding all the stuff you have to take care of to get a secure data transfer.